# AbstractMethodError using spray and akka

Tags: web-services, scala, akka, spray, spray-json

I want to make some webservices with spray and akka.
GET resquests works fine (get elements list, a value... with spray-json) but with my Authentication request, I got an expection, and I don't know why.
I've make some unit tests to see if serialization/deserialization works fine with marshallers, and I see a well formed json object.

Here's my stacktrace :

```
Uncaught error from thread [on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[on-spray-can]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.example.components.models.authentication.IdentityWithProfile$.viaSeq(Lscala/Function1;Lspray/json/JsonFormat;)Lspray/json/RootJsonFormat;
    at spray.json.CollectionFormats$class.seqFormat(CollectionFormats.scala:77)
    at com.example.components.models.authentication.IdentityWithProfile$.seqFormat(Identity.scala:15)
    at com.example.components.models.authentication.IdentityWithProfile$.<init>(Identity.scala:16)
    at com.example.components.models.authentication.IdentityWithProfile$.<clinit>(Identity.scala)
    at com.example.api.marshallers.AuthenticationResult$.<init>(AuthenticationResult.scala:12)
    at com.example.api.marshallers.AuthenticationResult$.<clinit>(AuthenticationResult.scala)
    at com.example.api.RouteService$$anonfun$authenticate$2.apply(RouteService.scala:23)
    at com.example.api.RouteService$$anonfun$authenticate$2.apply(RouteService.scala:23)
    at spray.routing.directives.RouteDirectives$$anonfun$complete$1$$anon$3.apply(RouteDirectives.scala:49)
    at spray.routing.directives.RouteDirectives$$anonfun$complete$1$$anon$3.apply(RouteDirectives.scala:48)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
    at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:29)
    at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:29)
    at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:29)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$handleExceptions$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ExecutionDirectives.scala:35)
    at spray.routing.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$handleExceptions$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ExecutionDirectives.scala:33)
    at spray.routing.HttpServiceBase$class.runSealedRoute$1(HttpService.scala:36)
    at spray.routing.HttpServiceBase$$anonfun$runRoute$1.applyOrElse(HttpService.scala:46)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at com.example.api.RouteActor.aroundReceive(RouteActor.scala:5)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I've found topics about this error, and the problem was scala/spray/akka versions, but I checked and I use correct versions (scala 2.10.4/spray 1.3.2/akka 2.3.6)

Anyone has a solution, or a track ?

EDIT : 
GET webservices don't work too... I think it's a configuration problem.

Comment: That `IdentityWithProfile` class was built against something different from what it's running against. Check your classpath and make sure you're not ending up with multiple versions of the same classes on there.

Comment: I had a case class `IdentityWithProfileResult` with an object with the same name which extends of DefaultJsonProtocol, where there is a jsonFormat and a marshaller. After comment this file, my GET request works again, but same error with my POST request..

Comment: What's your spray-json version?

Comment: My spray-json version is 1.3.1